# Complicated inequality proof

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I've run into a stumbling block as part of a larger problem where I need to show if

$$\sum_i w_i = 1$$

This implies

$$ \frac{\sum_j w_j^2( (1+w_j^2) +\sum_iw_i^2) }{\sum_i w_i^2 +1} \leq 1$$

I'm having a little trouble. The intuition is that since each $w_i$ is <1 $w_i^2$ has to be less than $w_i$ and similarly $w_i^4$ has to be even smaller. However, I'm having a hard time using this fact since we don't know what the $\sum_i w_i^2$ is bounded by?

Comment: obviously false. take only one $w$ and have it be $1$. $\frac{3}{2} \not \le 1$.

Comment: Okay suppose i is at least 2

Comment: have $w_2 = 0$.

Comment: fair enough....

Comment: If all $w_i$ are non-negative numbers you can actually show that this expression is less than $\frac{3}{2}$.

Otherwise, you can just take $w_1=N+1$, $w_2=-N$ everything else 0, and setting $N$ yo infinity you will show that our fraction is unbounded from above